# Trying to access menu names from array using structures ...getting error

Tags: c

I have a menu and sub-menu. I have created a structure where I have store menu and submenu names in an array. Trying to print them, but I think I am wrong somewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct calculator
{
    int x_loc;
    int y_loc;
    char main_menu[15];
    char sub_menu[15];
    char icon_title[100];
};

char *main_menu_names[3] = {"Link_1", "Link_2", "Link_3"};
char *sub_menu_names[3] = {"Sub_Link_1", "Sub_Link_2", "Sub_Link_3"};

struct calculator info = {219, 120, main_menu_names, sub_menu_names, "Title"};

int main()
{
    printf("X location: %d\n",info.x_loc);
    printf("Y location: %d\n",info.y_loc);

    printf("Menu Name: %s\n",info.main_menu);
    printf("sub menu: %s\n",info.sub_menu);
    printf("icon_title: %s\n",info.icon_title);

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

You can't initialize `struct calculator`'s `char main_menu[15]` field with `menu_names`, which is undefined. I don't believe you could compile the above.

Comment: It doesn't compile for a number of reasons, first and foremost because there is no such thing as `menu_names` that the declaration `struct calculator info = {219, 120, menu_names, sub_menu_names, "Title"};` can eat.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks. I sometimes read what I think I should be reading.

Comment: thanks for pointing it ...i have changed it ...but still it cant compile

Answer (score 0):

DEFINITION IS SINGLE ARRAY

```
char main_menu[15];
char sub_menu[15];
```

But u have equated to two dimensional array

```
char *main_menu_names[3] = {"Link_1", "Link_2", "Link_3"};
char *sub_menu_names[3] = {"Sub_Link_1", "Sub_Link_2", "Sub_Link_3"};
```

in

```
struct calculator info = {219, 120, menu_names, sub_menu_names, "Title"};
```

It should be like 
    struct calculator info = {219, 120, menu_names[0][0], sub_menu_names[0][0], "Title"};